# Dealing with KB, MB, GB and TB and bytes

Tags: javascript

This function is simple, it gets a number of bytes and returns its representation in either Bytes, KB, MB, GB and TB.

As simple as it is, I am sure there are other (and perhaps better ways) to write it.

```
function kmgtbytes (num) {
    if (num > 0 ){
        if (num < 1024)             { return [num, "Bytes"] }
        if (num < 1048576)          { return [num/1024, "KB"] }
        if (num < 1073741824)       { return [num/1024/1024, "MB"] }
        if (num < 1099511600000)    { return [num/1024/1024/1024, "GB"] }

        return [num/1024/1024/1024/1024, "TB"]
    }

    return num
}
```

Comment: Your primary concern should be the clarity of your code. minitech's answer is sweet and terse, yet your code requires little thought to discern its function. Both of you should add comments to your code indicating its purpose.

Comment: [jsPerf for all current answers](http://jsperf.com/size-suffix)

Comment: And yes, I think yours is the clearest! It’s also not right, though, as 1099511600000 < 1024^4.

Comment: Having your function return a different type as the default will probably cause type errors everywhere

Comment: This function lacks only a better name and an introductory comment (incl. examples of possible outputs). I haven't managed to come up with either, by the way.

Comment: @minitech I added another function, http://jsperf.com/size-suffix/3

Comment: You may find reading how [others have done it in the past](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/human.c) enlightening.

Comment: As @Eric mentions, the only thing I'd really change would be to remove the `if` and the `return num`. It makes more sense to return `[0, "Bytes"]` for an input of `0`, and presumably you don't care about the result for negative values.

Comment: @kojiro: you've got to be kidding (although it makes a good history lesson -- uses `go to` statements and everything!)

Comment: @SamGoldberg kidding? no. Did I think he should emulate a C lib in JS? Also no. History is for learning from, not copying verbatim. (That's why I made it a comment and didn't integrate it into an answer.)

Comment: Consider doubling the thresholds, such that valid outputs include "5 Bytes", "1024 Bytes", "2000 Bytes", "2047 Bytes", "2 kiB" (for 2048 ≤ *num* < 3072), etc.  Due to [Benford's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford's_law), a disproportionate number of files are likely to be reported as "1 kiB", so it would be nice to provide more precision.  Also, consider using [IEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) instead of SI binary prefixes to be more explicit.

Comment: I actually like the proposed question better than any proposed solution. The function is simple, clear and indicative of its internal logic with just a glance. My only suggestion would be to replace the literals with their composition for a quick indication of what they mean. This is, instead of `1048576` I would write `1024*1024` and so on. Perhaps throwing an exception if `num < 0`?

Answer (score 15):

Here's a slightly less repetitive way to write it since we know each unit is 1024 as large as the last:

```
function kmgtbytes (num) {
    var unit, units = ["TB", "GB", "MB", "KB", "Bytes"];
    for (unit = units.pop(); units.length && num >= 1024; unit = units.pop()) {
        num /= 1024;
    }
    return [num, unit];
}
```

Comment: I'll admit that using `pop()` is a little inefficient as you're creating and mutating the array of units on every call. Whether this is actually a problem depends on how often you expect to be calling this function, and your definition of "better" as used in the question :)

Comment: Why is the result of this function an array? Very surprising.

Answer (score 12):

What about:

```
var units=["Byte","KB","MB","GB","TB","PB"];

function getUnit(bytes){
    for(var i of units){
        if(bytes<1024) return bytes+" "+units[i];
        bytes/=1024;
    }
}
```

Edit:

It prevents you from precalculating your values for each if-clause. It's easily extensible: Just add another unit, wherever you want. And for the rest: it does its job in an easy understandable way. No rocket science.

Comment: Please don’t use `for…in` loops to iterate arrays. It’s darn slow and not necessarily accurate.

Comment: Optimizing this loop is barking up the wrong tree, even if it were slow. If that's the only "bottleneck" in your code, everything is okay I would say.

Comment: Yes, but a `for...in` loop isn't guaranteed to execute in order.  More reading [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Answer (score 11):

You can use logarithms:

```
var sizes = ["bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"];

function formatSize(bytes) {
    var l = Math.min(sizes.length - 1, Math.log(bytes) / Math.LN2 / 10 | 0);
    return [bytes / Math.pow(1024, l), sizes[l]];
}
```

The confusing part, `Math.log(bytes) / Math.LN2 / 10 | 0`, gets the base-1024 logarithm of `bytes` and truncates it.

Comment: The use of logarithm is a wise one!

Comment: Excessive use of floating point is icky for my taste, and also likely to perform worse.

Comment: @200_success: You can’t avoid floating-point here. 1024^4 > 2^32. Apart from that, “once, which forms the crux of this shortcut” is difficult to avoid :P

Comment: No doubt, the problem itself requires floating point, as the return value is FP.  It's the `Math.log()` that I find excessive.

Comment: @200_success: This is the fastest answer so far on Firefox 23.0, for what it’s worth. (Which is not very much.)

Comment: This works, and it appears to be sound, but it is much less expressive than the original. I inherently mistrust overly clever code because, as Brian Kernighan said, "Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?"

Comment: With that said, when you're optimizing performance, being clever can be very helpful, just be sure to write up enough unit tests to have reasonably good coverage.

Answer (score 9):

I will discuss 2 points to your code: Readability/Cleanliness and Robustness

From the Readability/Cleanliness perspective I'd argue that your code is the easiest to read vs any answer you've received thus far. I knew in 3 seconds the purpose of all of that code and wouldn't need any comments to further explain it.

From the robustness perspective it all boils down to the use case of the code. If you know without a doubt that you will only ever see positive sized numbers <1024 TB I'd say again your code is fine. If you wanted to handle file size differences (as in 100kb-150kb = -50kb) or file sizes beyond 1023TB then clearly you need to enhance your approach.

To handle the more general case this question has already been answered here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281640/how-do-i-get-a-human-readable-file-size-in-bytes-abbreviation-using-net/4975942#4975942

As a side note it would appear size=0 would return [0,] but size of 1 would return [1,Bytes]. You may want to return [0,Bytes]

Answer (score 3):

How about recursion? (http://jsfiddle.net/WhhCL/1/)

```
var units = ["Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"];

function unitize(num) {
    return unitizer(num, 0);
}

function unitizer(num, level) {
    if (num < 1024 || level > units.length - 1) {
        return num + " " + units[level];
    } else {
        return unitizer(num / 1024, level + 1);
    }
}
```

The readability of your original function is tough to beat. At least for now, it's also the most performant of the bunch.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a while loop, divide by 1024 and keep track of how many times you divided.

This is my completely bonkers function:

```
function resolve_to_power_of(bytes, power) {
    var powers;
    powers = 0;
    while (bytes >= power) {
        powers += 1;
        bytes = bytes / power;
    }
    return {
        quantity: bytes,
        powers: powers
    };
}

function format_default(bytes) {
    var resolved, descriptors;
    resolved = resolve_to_power_of(bytes, 1024);
    descriptors = [ "B", "KB", "MB", "TB", "GB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB" ];
    return Math.ceil(resolved.quantity) + " " + descriptors[resolved.powers];
}

format_default(1024); // 1 KB
format_default(1000); // 1000 B
format_default(102400); // 100 KB
```

The reason it's set up like this is because it also supports dividing by `1000` and other byte lables like `[ "B", "K", "M" .. ]` etc. following IEC and SI standards.

Comment: why while loop?

Comment: Because it makes the most sense: keep dividing _while_ the number is larger than or equal to 1024.

Comment: You can use `++` and `/=` and `var powers = 0;`, if you’re not against that sort of formatting. (I’d do `/=`, though.)

Comment: @minitech, it's good practice to separate variable declaration and instantiation in JavaScript. Scripts should generally be written as with an order of: variable declaration, function declaration, initialization, execution. Doing this the more verbose way helps avoid some variable hoisting issues, and some initialization ordering issues.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I don’t agree with that at all, but I did add “if you’re not against that sort of formatting”.

Comment: @minitech My coding style aims to increase readability, extensibility and maintainability and decrease the chance of errors. This code passes JSLint checks. Nick's solution is very clever, it uses only 6 lines. I also had to read it twice to make sure there is no off-by-one error. It has the most upvotes because we measure code quality by the least number of characters and best use of obscure functions. /sarcasm. If I found this code in one of my applications I would ask him to rewrite it.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the thousands until the number is small enough, then just return the remaining number and the corresponding unit:

```
function kmgtbytes(num) {
  for (var i = 0; num >= 1024 && i < 4; i++) num /= 1024;
  return [num, ["Bytes","kB","MB","GB","TB"][i]];
}
```